# My app crashes when i try to dynamically create elements in this loop

Tags: javascript

```
    (696) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
    119:
     article: "Consultant: vision 2010 ready for action steps"
     date: "2005-03-04 00:00:00"
     volume: "32"
     issue: "7"
     page: "8"
     reporter: null
     office1: null
     office2: null
     subject1: null
     subject2: null
     person1: "Massy, William"
     person2: "Pestello, Fred"
     person3: null
     memo: null
     __proto__: Object
    120:
     CampusReportID: "4"
     Title: "Readying For Change."
     DocumentTypeID: "1"
     ContentNoteID: "2"
     IssueID: "674"
     Page: "3"
     Notes: "This is a list of the presidential transition committee."
     __proto__: Object
```

i get response from from backend in the above format

when i try to display them by creating a div and para and appending it to another div in html, the app crashes

```
   for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
          {
             for(var propName in data) {
             if(data.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
             var propValue = data[propName];
             for(var key in propValue)
             {
              if(propValue.hasOwnProperty(key))
             {
                             var newProp = propValue[key];
                             console.log(newProp);
                             document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = newProp;
                             var divElement = document.createElement('div');
                             var paraElement = document.createElement('p');
                             paraElement.innerHTML= key+": "+newProp;
                             divElement.appendChild(paraElement);
                             var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
                             mainDiv.appendChild(divElement);
                           }
                         }
                     }
                 }  
               }

   <div id="mainDiv">
   </div>
```

i guess as there are too many results that are coming, it is taking long and crashing, someone help me how to deal with this

Comment: Modifying the DOM is relatively expensive; you may get better performance by constructing the new elements as an HTML string inside the loop, and then adding the result to the DOM all at once.

Comment: please share a codepen or codesandbox link here. And also please share your required output. That would help to solve your issue easily.

Comment: Paging... implement paging.

Comment: for this type of functionality better to try any of the framework or library.